# How to call python function from JS in odoo?

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-9

I have a boolean field in my model, I want to call python function when this boolean field change using JS? How can I achieved this?

Answer (score 1):

Check some examples in the original source code. You can call python methods with `call`:

```js
var def_session = new openerp.Model("im_chat.session").call("session_info", [], {"ids" : [session_id]}).then(function(session){
    conv = self.activate_session(session, false);
    conv.received_message(message);
});
```